# Is there any alternative for $function in older version of mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to call an JavaScript function and pass document key values as a parameters to the function , in latest version of mongo dB there is pipeline operator called `$function` , is there any way I can achieve this in older versions of mongo DB ?

Comment: it will help if you have a sample JSON/example, as far as I know, there is no similar $function in previous releases i.e releases before 4.4. we can explore alternate(if any) if you cant upgrade your Mongo DB instance to 4.4

Comment: @Mallik , Yeah , updated mongodb o latest version , Thank you